# Including a C++ file in a different group into a Objective-C++ Test

Tags: c++, xcode, xctest

I'm writing a C++ library, but want to be able to test it with XCTest.
I am using XCode, and have gotten it working with an absolute path:

```
#import "/Users/kurt/Workspace/ProcSim/ProcSim/Access.cpp"
```

However, this is gross. I'd like to be able to do `#import "ProcSim/Access.cpp"` or even just `#import "Access.cpp"`, but since the tests are in the `ProcSim/Tests` folder and my source is in `ProcSim`, I can't figure out how to include the .cpp into the .mm test file and XCode be able to find it.

I am using XCode 5.0.1

Comment: Why are you including a `.cpp` file?

Comment: The .hpp fails in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the .cpp file is not in your project directory? Correct?

If so..

Click the Project Symbol in Xcode -> Build Settings -> **Header Search Paths** ->

change it to "/Users/kurt/Workspace/ProcSim/ProcSim/"

Then do `#import <Access.cpp>`

Comment: It's in the same project, just a different group

Comment: It turns out that you have to add `$(PROJECT_DIR)` to the Test target under build settings as a Header Search Path.

Then you have to add your cpp files as compile sources under build phases to make the linker happy.

After all this, the `#import 'Group/File.hpp'` syntax will work happily.